# Changing background color of a view?

Tags: android, view, background, android-linearlayout

I want to create a subclass of `linear layout`,and it's background color must be change Black or White.I wrote this code:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout implements Runnable {

    int color = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(color == 0xFF000000){
                    color = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                }else{
                    color = 0xFF000000;
                }
                this.setBackgroundColor(color);
                postInvalidate();
                System.out.println("Color >> " + color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And then I set it as ContentView of my Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyLayout(this));
    }
```

After running App in Emulator,`run` method of `MyLayout` executes without any exception,but backgroung color is always Black.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: when you change the color? please post code

Comment: what u are getting in `System.out.println("Color >> " + color);` line in logcat?

Comment: @CsehTamás I'm trying to change color in `run` method.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K logcat repeats:<br/>Color >> -16777216
<br/>Color >> -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following up @Hisham Muneer,I send instance of my Activity to my class and it works.`runOnUiThread` is a method in `Activity` class.This is finall code:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout implements Runnable {

    int color = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    Activity context;

    public MyLayout(Activity context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        myView = this;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    private View myView;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (color == 0xFF000000) {
                            color = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        } else {
                            color = 0xFF000000;
                        }
                        myView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                        postInvalidate();
                        System.out.println("Color >> " + color);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Try this its working.

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout implements Runnable {

    int color = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myView = this;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    private View myView;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (color == 0xFF000000) {
                            color = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        } else {
                            color = 0xFF000000;
                        }
                        myView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                        postInvalidate();
                        System.out.println("Color >> " + color);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Whenever you want to make any change in you User Interface through a other thread, run your code inside runOnUiThread.

Comment: I tried that,but I got this error:The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type MyLayout

Comment: @StudentStudent maybe you can mark my answer as correct, if that really helps

Answer (score 1):

Try invalidate() where you tried postInvalidate()

Other tip:
You are creating a new LinearLayout, **without specifying layout size.**
I recommend you use setLayoutParams() before using setContentView:

```
MyLayout layout = new MyLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(...));
this.setContentView(layout);
```

At this moment, you are creating a new Layout 0 sized (height and width)

Comment: I tried invalidate() instead of postInvalidate() and this layoutparams :"LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);" But no things change.

Comment: Did you set lp instance to the layout?

Comment: Thank you for your Attention.Please see my answer.+1 up vote for your helpful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change this in a Thread use a Asynctask

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //HERE YOU CAN CHANGE THE COLOR
      }
```